# JPA Criteria API in with two lists

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, criteria, builder

I've been searching for a while and I don't find what i want...

Here is my code :

```
public List<MasseSalariale> findMasseSalarialeByCriteria(List<Section> sections,
  Integer exercice, List<BpCaEtats> etats) {

    List<String> etatString = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (BpCaEtats e : etats) {
      etatString.add(BpCaEtats.bpCaEtatToString(e));
    }

    CriteriaBuilder builder = this.getCriteriaBuilder();

    CriteriaQuery<MasseSalariale> query = builder.createQuery(MasseSalariale.class);
    Root<MasseSalariale> masseSalariale = query.from(MasseSalariale.class);
    Join<MasseSalariale, Etablissement> etablissement =
    masseSalariale.join(MasseSalariale_.etablissement);

    Predicate p1 = builder.equal(masseSalariale.get(MasseSalariale_.annee), exercice);

    Expression<List<Section>> exp2 = etablissement.get(Etablissement_.sections);
    Predicate p2 = exp2.in(sections);

    Expression<String> exp3 = masseSalariale.get(MasseSalariale_.etat);
    Predicate p3 = exp3.in(etatString);

    query.select(masseSalariale).where(builder.and(p1, p2, p3));

    return this.find(query);

}
```

Basically, I need to know if one (at least) value in the section list from etablissement is contained in the section list in parameter. But the predicate p2 is wrong I think...

Comment: Basically, what you  want to do is a Join between your list and the one in the entity. AFAIK, it cannot be with standard JPA. If the list that you pass is small, maybe multiple IN clauses linked by OR may be usable.

Comment: IN is to check if ONE SPECIFIC value is in a Collection

Comment: So, can I check if there is a value contained in the two lists with JPA criteria ? (without multiple IN)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using ListJoin, it worked well :

```
ListJoin<Etablissement, Section> sectionsEtab = etablissement.join(Etablissement_.sections);
Predicate p2 = sectionsEtab.in(sections);
```

Thanks